# api platform graphql query resolver not triggered

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I have entity `Product`:

```
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\GraphQl\Query;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\GraphQl\QueryCollection;
use App\UI\ApiPlatform\Resolver\ProducsCollectionResolver;
use App\UI\ApiPlatform\Resolver\ProductResolver;

#[ApiResource(
    graphQlOperations: [
        new Query(
            resolver: ProductResolver::class,
        ),
        new QueryCollection(
            resolver: ProducsCollectionResolver::class,
        ),
    ]
)]
class Product
{
    public function __construct(
        private string $id,
        public string $name
    ){}
}
```

and query resolver:

```
use ApiPlatform\GraphQl\Resolver\QueryItemResolverInterface;
use App\UI\ApiPlatform\Entity\Product;

final class ProductResolver implements QueryItemResolverInterface
{
    public function __invoke($item, array $context): Product
    {
        dump('here');
        return new Product('id', 'name');
    }
}
```

in `/graphql` I can see Product resource with id and name, but running query

```
{
  product(id: "id") {
    name
  }
}
```

and getting error

```
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Internal server error",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 32,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "product"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "debugMessage": "No route matches \"586b8f112f7d8059668e5f73\".",
        "file": "/srv/app/vendor/api-platform/core/src/Symfony/Routing/IriConverter.php",
        "line": 69,
        "trace": [
          {
            "file": "/srv/app/vendor/api-platform/core/src/GraphQl/Resolver/Stage/ReadStage.php",
            "line": 99,
            "call": "ApiPlatform\\Symfony\\Routing\\IriConverter::getResourceFromIri()"
          },
  ...
```

and it looks like my custom resolver not triggered as I do not see my dumped debug string. I have autowiring enabled in Symfony, but I also tried by adding resolver in `services.yaml` with tag `api_platform.graphql.query_resolver`, but still the same.

UPDATE:
I also tried query like this:

```
{
  product(id: "/products/586b8f112f7d8059668e5f73") {
    id
  }
}
```

it also does not work, but error is different now

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Provider not found on operation \"_api_/products/{id}{._format}_get\"",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 32,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "product"
      ],
```

and similar situation for collection query:

```
{
  products(first:1) {
    edges {
      node {
        id, name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and error is `Provider not found on operation \"collection_query\"`

UPDATE 2: I also add custom provider:

```
#[ApiResource(
    graphQlOperations: [
        new Query(
            provider: ProductProvider::class,
            resolver: ProductResolver::class,
        ),
    ]
)]
```

here is provider:

```
inal class ProductProvider implements ProviderInterface
{
    public function provide(Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = []): object|null|array
    {
        return new Product('id', 'name');
}
```

and resolver now doing  nothing:

```
class ProductResolver implements QueryItemResolverInterface
{
    public function __invoke($item, array $context): Product
    {
        return $item;
    }
}
```

but still the same error `Provider not found on operation \"_api_/products/{id}{._format}_get\"`. What is wrong? I have another service, I checked dozen times already, configurations the same, but in that other service it works, but in this case not :(

Comment: Are you on 2.7 or are you on 3.0? I'm having this issue on 2.7 but API platform won't take bug reports on 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got this working for at least Api Platform `^3.0` - you can specify the data provider for the `ApiResource`, so when it needs to get the value outside of a `Query` or `QueryCollection` (eg, when it searches for it internally), you can point it to the same provider as your `Query()`.

In my case, it was doing this:

```php
#[ApiResource(
    // add the provider here!
    provider: BookItemDataProvider::class,
    graphQlOperations: [
        new QueryCollection(
            provider: BookCollectionDataProvider::class,
        ),
        new Query(
            provider: BookItemDataProvider::class,
            paginationEnabled: false
    ),
    ],
    paginationType: 'page'
)]
```